# How to write formulas for counting different values in data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, count, formula

The assignment is as follows.

Q2. Write a function with one argument, say, `data`.
The function does following,

1. If the argument data is a character vector, count the total number of characters;
2. If the argument data is numeric vector, calculate the mean, sd, min, and max values;
3. The function should return the value using list, containing also `data`.

I am very new to this and would like to use basic R code to solve it. I don't really understand the syntax I ought to use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to upload some data examples. I am assuming your 'data' is pure character or numbers. See code below. But detailed information will be needed if it does not work for you.

```
myfunc=function(data){
  if(is.character(data)){
    res=list(data=data, Nchar=sum(nchar(data)))
  }
  else if(is.numeric(data)){
    res=list(data=data, mean=mean(data), sd=sd(data),max=max(data), min=min(data))
  }
  return(res)
}
#usage
data1=c("a","bbb")
myfunc(data1)
data2=c(1,2,3)
myfunc(data2)
```